# can XML be send as response to iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, servlets, iframe

I am trying send xml data as response to `iframe` which is dynamically generated. i am sending the follwing data as response

```
out.println(  
     "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>\n" +   
         " <response> " + My_data +  "</response>" );
```

when i check using `firebug` i only see the follwing `innerHTML`

`<response> My_data </response>`

if i am trying to parse the xml i get `uncaught exception: Invalid XML` error. here is my `js`

```
   var xml = this.contentDocument.body.innerHTML,  /* this : iframe id */
       xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ), 
       $xml = $( xmlDoc ), 
       $title = $xml.find( "<file-url>" ); 
          alert($title.text());
```

How can i send XML response & parse.

Comment: How dou you load XML into  that IFRAME. Consider using AJAX to get XML response to JS.

Comment: @JanPfeifer: `in servlet : response.setContentType("text/xml")` and then it can be load into iframe. i send back response as `XML` data but only thing i am getting error during parsing of response XML.

Answer (score 0):

It is generaly a good idea to use AJAX. How do you actually load that xml into an IFRAME? By using static SRC or Javascript? You have also typos in your code.

- Javascript command has to end with semicolon not a comma
- [jQuery.find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) accepts only name of the tag without *<>*
- You can prepend a xml header (<?xml ..?>) just before your innerHTML, but its not neccessary here

---

This should work:

```
var xml    = this.contentDocument.body.innerHTML,  /* this : iframe id */
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );
var $xml   = $( xmlDoc );
var $title = $xml.find( "file-url" ); 
      alert($title.text());
```

Comment: yes, you are right. using `AJAX` is a good idea to handle `XML` data but i am uploading a file `<input type="file" />` from client to server that is why i can't use `AJAX` for this functionality.

Comment: i am getting error at the first line `this.contentDocument.body.innerHTML : undefined`

Comment: So use instead of _this_ document.getElementById('yourFrameID').contentDocument

Comment: `this` represents as an `object` of certain `element/selecter` so in my case `this` object would work instead of other form. BTW i find the sol'n e.g. `$(this).find('body').html();` but getting another error which require some more research. Anyway thanks for your time & help